# Why can i have only one instance of Calendar object

Tags: java, calendar

I was just wondering...

why can i have only one instance of Calendar object. Is there a reason for it to be a singleton?

I have tried to read the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) but they didn't mention why this is needed. And a quick google search didn't give me any answers.

Comment: [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is not a singleton and you can have multiple instances. Show us the code where you have a problem.

Comment: i don't have any problems with the code, i was just wondering ...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Calendar is not a singleton, it is an abstract class. The `getInstance` method is a Factory method that returns a concrete implementation of the Calendar class.

Search Google for java.util.Calendar source code, and you will see how it works.

Answer (score 10):

It is not singleton.

This:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Calendar c1, c2;
        c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        System.out.println(c1);
        System.out.println(c2);
    }
```

Outputs:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Jerusalem",offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Asia/Jerusalem,offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=26,startDayOfWeek=6,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=1,endMonth=8,endDay=13,endDayOfWeek=0,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2011,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=21,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=19,DAY_OF_YEAR=139,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=10,HOUR_OF_DAY=10,MINUTE=21,SECOND=27,MILLISECOND=839,ZONE_OFFSET=7200000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1305789687839,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Jerusalem",offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=143,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Asia/Jerusalem,offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=26,startDayOfWeek=6,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=1,endMonth=8,endDay=13,endDayOfWeek=0,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2011,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=21,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=19,DAY_OF_YEAR=139,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=10,HOUR_OF_DAY=10,MINUTE=21,SECOND=27,MILLISECOND=839,ZONE_OFFSET=7200000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

(Which is different as you can see)

BTW, quick search for [source code returns](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Calendar.java.html):

```
public static synchronized Calendar getInstance() {
       return new GregorianCalendar();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Did you think that it is a singleton because it has a [`getInstance()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance())? That's not the case!

`getInstance()` returns a new instance each time.

Comment: yes, exactly because of that. and now i feel dumb because of it :/

Comment: @Gabriel no, the API designers should feel dumb. It's a miserably designed API, which is why anybody with common sense uses Jodatime instead

Comment: "anybody with common sense and not bound by some stupid restrictions that require him to use the native classes" ... sigh.

Comment: @Joachim I know, I've been there too :-)

Comment: It's the normal case that `get` methods returning a mutable object return a new instance. `static` methods returning a shared instance of a mutable object should be burnt.

Comment: @Tom: however `getInstance()` *does* kind-of imply a singleton. I'd call it `newInstance()` if it always created a new instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can have as many instances of `Calendar` as you want ... modulo that it is an abstract class, so you are talking about of instances of *child classes* of Calendar.

Perhaps you think that the `getInstance()` method returns a singleton object?  It doesn't.  It creates and returns a new object each time you call it.

(The javadoc doesn't explicitly state that the calendar is not a singleton, but it says *"The Calendar returned is based on the current time ..."*.  That implies that it is returning a new object each time ... because the current time keeps changing.  And anyway, that's what the method does if you'd care to look at the source code.)