# Adding multiple days to a Calendar in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I'm writing a program in which I need to work with dates. I'm receiving an Input date, which is the starting Day of a Week (Monday). In this case it is Mon Jan 05 00:00:00 CET 2015.
Then I need to  define the dates for the other days of the week.

I tried to do it this way:

```
Calendar cStart = Calendar.getInstance();   

     Calendar cMon = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cTue = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cWed = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cThu = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cFri = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cSat = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cSun = Calendar.getInstance();

                cMon = cStart;
                cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                cTue = cStart;
                cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                cWed = cStart;
                cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                cThu = cStart;
                cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                cFri = cStart;
                cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                cSat = cStart;
                cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                cSun = cStart;

                System.out.println(cMon.getTime());
                System.out.println(cTue.getTime());
                System.out.println(cWed.getTime());
                System.out.println(cThu.getTime());
                System.out.println(cFri.getTime());
                System.out.println(cSat.getTime());
                System.out.println(cSun.getTime());
```

Now my problem is, that the output should look like this:

```
Mon Jan 05 00:00:00 CET 2015
Tue Jan 06 00:00:00 CET 2015
Wed Jan 07 00:00:00 CET 2015
Thu Jan 08 00:00:00 CET 2015
Fri Jan 09 00:00:00 CET 2015
Sat Jan 10 00:00:00 CET 2015
Sun Jan 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
```

But actually it is looking like this:

```
Sun Jan 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
Sun Jan 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
Sun Jan 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
Sun Jan 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
Sun Jan 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
Sun Jan 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
Sun Jan 11 00:00:00 CET 2015
```

What can I do, to receive the output that I need?

Comment: Just a small hint: `Calendar.getInstance()` always returns the same physical object. So every variable (`cMon`, `cTue`, etc.) you're using is pointing to exactly the same object. Try using new instance of `Calendar`.

Comment: you can keep the same code and add the System.out.println() statement each time you add a day to your Calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the reference of `cStart` to every of your variables. Use the `clone()` method, to get a new object every time.

```
Calendar cStart = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar cMon = null;
Calendar cTue = null;
Calendar cWed = null;
Calendar cThu = null;
Calendar cFri = null;
Calendar cSat = null;
Calendar cSun = null;

cMon = (Calendar) cStart.clone();
cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cTue = (Calendar) cStart.clone();
cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cWed = (Calendar) cStart.clone();
cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cThu = (Calendar) cStart.clone();
cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cFri = (Calendar) cStart.clone();
cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cSat = (Calendar) cStart.clone();
cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cSun = (Calendar) cStart.clone();

System.out.println(cMon.getTime());
System.out.println(cTue.getTime());
System.out.println(cWed.getTime());
System.out.println(cThu.getTime());
System.out.println(cFri.getTime());
System.out.println(cSat.getTime());
System.out.println(cSun.getTime());
```

**Output**

```
Mon Feb 22 12:45:39 CET 2016
Tue Feb 23 12:45:39 CET 2016
Wed Feb 24 12:45:39 CET 2016
Thu Feb 25 12:45:39 CET 2016
Fri Feb 26 12:45:39 CET 2016
Sat Feb 27 12:45:39 CET 2016
Sun Feb 28 12:45:39 CET 2016
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 provides a new time API.
You could solve your problem quit nicely with it.

```
// There are various ways to set your start day
LocalDate start = LocalDate.now();

// Year - Month - Day
start = LocalDate.parse("2016-02-26");
start = LocalDate.of(2016,2,26);


LocalDate cMon = start.plusDays(1);
LocalDate cTue = start.plusDays(2);
LocalDate cWed = start.plusDays(3);
LocalDate cThu = start.plusDays(4);
LocalDate cFri = start.plusDays(5);
LocalDate cSat = start.plusDays(6);
LocalDate cSun = start.plusDays(7);

System.out.println(cMon);
System.out.println(cTue);
System.out.println(cWed);
System.out.println(cThu);
System.out.println(cFri);
System.out.println(cSat);
System.out.println(cSun);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar cStart` is a *reference* to a calendar object so when you do `cMon = cStart;` you are copying the reference to the same object.  As you keep modifying the one and only Calendar object, all the references point to the same thing.

You can use `clone()` to get a copy of the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use `clone()` as mentioned in the other answers to duplicate the `Calendar` instance for every weekday variable.
**Or** you use the `Date` class that is designed to store a Date while `Calendar` is designed to calculate Dates.

```
Calendar cStart = Calendar.getInstance();   

Date cMon = null;
Date cTue = null;
[...]

cMon = cStart.getTime();
cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cTue = cStart.getTime();
cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
[...]

System.out.println(cMon);
System.out.println(cTue);
[...]
```

Comment: Class `Calendar` is *not* a singleton. Its (confusingly named) `getInstance()` method does not always return the same instance; it returns a new instance every time you call it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055112/why-can-i-have-only-one-instance-of-calendar-object

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cStart = Calendar.getInstance();   
System.out.println(cStart.getTime());

     for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
       cStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

       System.out.println(cStart.getTime());
     }
```

Comment: Please try to include some comments/explanation with your code to help others understand.