# Codename One PickerComponent setStartDate and setEndDate usage

Tags: codenameone

I tried the following code to set the startDate and endDate of a PickerComponent:

CSS:

```
#Constants {
    includeNativeBool: true; 
    lightweightPickerBool: true; /* It's necessary to use the "setStartDate" and "setEndDate" of the Picker */
}
```

MainClass:

```
    Form f = new Form(new TextModeLayout(1, 1));
    int MINAGE = 13;

    Calendar minAge = Calendar.getInstance(); // it's not a singleton, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055112/why-can-i-have-only-one-instance-of-calendar-object
    minAge.setTime(new Date()); // current time
    int year = minAge.get(Calendar.YEAR) - MINAGE;
    minAge.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    Date endDate = minAge.getTime();

    Calendar maxAge = Calendar.getInstance();
    maxAge.setTime(new Date());
    maxAge.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1930);
    maxAge.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    maxAge.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    Date startDate = maxAge.getTime();

    PickerComponent inputCmp = PickerComponent.createDate(endDate).label("Birthday");
    Log.p("startDate: " + startDate.toString());
    Log.p("endDate: " + endDate.toString());
    inputCmp.getPicker().setStartDate(startDate);
    inputCmp.getPicker().setEndDate(endDate);

    f.add(inputCmp);
    f.show();
```

but when I try to select the date in the picker, I get:

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,293 - startDate: Sat Feb 01 12:30:58 CET 1930
[EDT] 0:0:0,307 - endDate: Fri Dec 02 12:30:58 CET 2005
[EDT] 0:0:2,227 - Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - Index out of bounds
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index out of bounds
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.SpinnerNode.setSelectedIndex(SpinnerNode.java:284)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.SpinnerNode.rebuildChildren(SpinnerNode.java:213)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.SpinnerNode.setListModel(SpinnerNode.java:227)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.Spinner3D.setModel(Spinner3D.java:207)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.DateSpinner3D.setEndYear(DateSpinner3D.java:340)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.DateSpinner3D.setDateRange(DateSpinner3D.java:216)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.Picker$1.createDatePicker3D(Picker.java:490)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.Picker$1.showInteractionDialog(Picker.java:605)
    at com.codename1.ui.spinner.Picker$1.actionPerformed(Picker.java:303)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:570)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:604)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:708)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:3339)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:4528)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2079)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1051)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:969)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Tested in the Simulator.

Comment: I updated the question adding the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in `Picker` I asked a user in the past to submit an issue on this but it seems that he didn't. It seems the default behavior of picker is to show 1970 as the oldest date. This is obviously problematic and should be addressed.

Comment: Ok, bug reported: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2633