# How is memory leak happening in this scenario?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am not able to understand how memory leak is happening in my application. I have a simple code that reproduces the error as follows:

In the `MainActivity`. I create a calendar instance and update milliseconds in a TextView

```
private lateinit var calendar: Calendar

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // Example of a call to a native method
    sample_text.text = stringFromJNI()


    statBtn.setOnClickListener{
        calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()
        sample_text.text = calendar.timeInMillis.toString()
    }

}
```

When I run the application just press the `statBtn` the app works fine (I see time updating in a TextView). However logcat reports the following

```
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=24KB, data=26KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=24KB, data=26KB
I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=57KB, data=54KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=57KB, data=54KB
I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
```

### EDIT

This code leaks too:

```
package com.example.blabla.d344

import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "Main Activity"
    //private lateinit var task: LongTask
    private var idx=0
    private lateinit var calendar: Calendar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Example of a call to a native method
        sample_text.text = stringFromJNI()
        calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()

        statBtn.setOnClickListener{

            //sample_text.text = calendar.timeInMillis.toString()
        }

    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    external fun stringFromJNI(): String

    companion object {

        // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a new instance of `GregorianCalendar` each time you press the button? `getInstance()` is not a singleton, [it's a factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055112/why-can-i-have-only-one-instance-of-calendar-object), which may explain the increased memory usage until GC happens.

Comment: @MichaelDodd If I move the creation of `GregorianCalendar` outside the `OnClickListener` the time no longer updates. AND the problem is still there, the code cache still increases. Also, why is GC not smart enough?

Comment: Are you able to isolate it down to a single line? i.e. comment out all but one of the lines / set `sample_text.text` to a constant String value until you find the one line that seems to increase the memory?

Comment: @MichaelDodd Kindly take a look at the updated post

Comment: Memory dump could be way more helpful. The console messages do not look like you have a memory leak, it may be a normal way an application is being executed far beyond your activity class code.

Comment: @EugenePetrenko When I keep pressing the `ststBtn` the memory (code capacity) goes on increasing.

Comment: The GC is normally lazy, it may not collect memory instantly. Instead, it may wait for some time, while there is enough memory. Thus you may see unneeded objects that are not yet collected. The memory dump will help to see it. It could have been the internals of the Android framework which create objects to handle the click (at least you need a click/touch event object to be allocated).

Comment: @EugenePetrenko That makes sense. Is memory dump a definitive way to identify memory leak? How do I create and analyze the memory dump?

Comment: Take a look at what you have in Android Studio, e.g. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler